# C++ generate next key

Tags: c++, string

```
const int SIZE = 3;
const char val[SIZE] = {'3', 'z', '7'};

const string& next(){
   static string ret = "0";
   static unsigned i = 0;
   static unsigned j = 0;
   s[j] = val[i];
   i++;

   return ret;

//...
}
```

Everytime next is called, I want it to return the next string key, such as:

```
3
z
7
33
3z
37
z3
zz
z7
73
7z
77
333
33z
...
```

val[] could be any size with any values.  My implementation is wrong and incomplete, and I can't wrap my head around it.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of wrapping your head around it, you can think of it like you would incrementing a number.  Increment the right-most value, but if that goes past the end then set it back to the first value and increment the next column, etc., then adding an extra value at the front if necessary.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const int n = 3;
const char val[n] = {'3', 'z', '7'};

const std::string& next()
{
    static std::string ret;
    if (ret.empty()) return ret = val[0];
    for (int i = ret.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        if (ret[i] == val[n - 1])
        {
            // carry situation, reset this column & will increment next...
            ret[i] = val[0];
        }
        else
        {
            // found existing column with room to increment...
            ret[i] = strchr(val, ret[i])[1];
            return ret;
        }

    return ret = val[0] + ret; // add an extra column at left...
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        std::cout << next() << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const string& next(){
    static int pos = 1;
    static string s;
    s.clear();
    int n = pos++;
    while (n){
        s += val[(n-1) % SIZE];
        // use s = val[(n-1] % SIZE] + s; for inverse order.
        n = (n-1) / SIZE;
    };
    return s;
};
```

Comment: this is annoying because it's very simple and it works (except that it's backward), but i can't figure out why..

Comment: `string` doesn't have a constructor from `char`, but you don't need one anyway - just `val[(n-1) % SIZE] + s`

Comment: @Tony: Thanks. I use C mostly :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to format a number in base 3, with unusual symbols for your digits. You can use `itoa` to convert to base 3 and then modify the string by changing 0 to 3, 1 to z, and 2 to 7.

Comment: I thought of that too, but that is actually not the case if you look at it carefully.

Comment: just to explain kynnysmatto's comment: when counting in base 3, we go from say 2 to 10 without having a "00" value; the consequence is skipped values where val[0] would have been in the left-most column.